# OpenShift 3 MySQL installation error

Tags: mysql, openshift, openshift-3, openshift-online

> Cannot create persistent volume claim "mysql". persistentvolumeclaims "mysql" is forbidden: exceeded quota: 6176696e6173686b616e74616b-noncompute, requested: requests.storage=1Gi, used: requests.storage=0, limited: requests.storage=0

I have paid account in OpenShift 3.

Can anyone help get this resolved?

Comment: Did you add storage to your account? If you go under Resources->Quota, how much storage does it say you have access to? If you go under Storage, what persistent volumes are already claimed?

Comment: Thank you so much. issue got resolved.@GrahamDumpleton